# ASP.NET 2.0 not handling static files under IIS 7

Tags: asp.net

We recently migrated from IIS 6 on windows 2003 server to IIS 7 on windows 2008 server.  Our applications are using ASP.NET Framework 2.0 and a custom Forms Authentication module.

The issue that we have is that ASP.NET is handling native ASP.NET file types (ex .aspx), but not static files (images, documents, pdf’s, etc).  So when a user accesses our site, they get prompted to login.  But if they access a file directly, they do not get prompted to login, and are served the file.  This is a primary concern where we have a restricted folder under the root folder.  The root is not secured, but the restricted folder is, and we have links to documents on the home page directly to files in that folder (you can see now how the users are accessing the files directly).

Our site is set up to use Classic Mode as described in the following article.  We have followed the instructions, but our static files are still not secured.

http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/508/wildcard-script-mapping-and-iis-integrated-pipeline/

Please note: This procedure does work on our local computers (Windows 7, IIS7).  But when performing the exact same steps on our servers, we are not getting prompted to log in for static files.

Comment: Post the handlers section of your web.config.

Comment: This might help...
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9925346/get-net-to-handle-all-requests-in-iis7